# Is there a way to have tabbed Google Drive panels?

Tags: google-drive

I have many Google accounts linked together and find myself constantly needing to switch to another account (thus opening up yet another tab) just to access a file via that other account. Is there a setting or plugin that allows a tabbed interface for multiple accounts. It doesn't even have to be directly on Google Drive's website. I'm just looking for a better interface for multiple account management.

Comment: Google Drive client nor within a browser is going to allow you to see multiple Google Drive accounts at once.  So this means you would have to use a third-party client if you want that capability.

Answer (score 0):

After a quick search, it looks like odrive is a free option that will allow you to manage multiple googledrive (and other cloud drive accounts) in one interface. I haven't tested it, so I can't speak to how reliable or user-friendly it is. It's worth a shot to test out, though.

http://techcrunch.com/2014/10/17/odrive/

https://www.odrive.com/m/